# Multiple HTML5 desktop notifications not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Chrome, things work OK (multiple notifications display at the same time). But in Firefox when there are multiple notifications NONE get displayed. Please see fiddle for a demo:

**http://jsfiddle.net/e6ps2/3/**

Scenario: I have a loop that reads through an array of things to be displayed as notifications.

I started off using Notify.js a nice javascript wrapper to the notifications api. And I thought the problem may be related to that. Then I tried using the api directly and the problem persisted.

So I would like to layer the notifications on top of each other if possible (which is how it should happen - and does happen in Chrome). But a possible fallback is to queue the notifications and using notify.js notifyClose() callback function to open the next notification in the queue - but have no idea how to do this.

```
if (Notify.isSupported()) {
    //Notify wrapper Notifications
     if (Notify.needsPermission()) Notify.requestPermission();
     //var j = 1; //uncomment this for single notification
     var j = 2;
     for (var i=0;i<j;i++) {
          var my_notification = new Notify('Hello World ' + i, {
                                    body: 'Some message here ' + i,
                                    tag:  "notify_" + i
                                });


         //uncomment below to show the notify plugin html5 notifications and then comment out the bare bones one
         //my_notification.show();

         //HTML5 bare nones  Notifications
         var notification = new Notification("Hi there! " + i, {
                                body: 'Some message here ' + i,
                                tag:  "Hello_"+ i
                            });

     }  
} else {alert("not supported"); }
```

Hope this all makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For first issue... If permission hasn't been given, you need to give a callback to fire when requesting permission. Moving the send code into a function, allow it to be called standalone, or as the callback

```
if (Notify.needsPermission()) {
    Notify.requestPermission(queueNotifications);
} else {
     queueNotifications();   
}
```

Regarding the queueing... I've had a similar issue and Firefox's implementation is poor compared to Chromes. Nevertheless, notifications can be queued using the following method:

- create timeinterval variable
- using the Notification onshow event, set a timeout with the interval to hide the notification
- move the sending of the notification into a separate function that can be called by a timeout inside of the for loop

  ```
  if (Notify.isSupported()) {
  var 
  showTimeout,
  displayTime = 5000,
  queueNotifications = function(){
      var i,
      j = 3;
      for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
          setTimeout(sendNotifications, displayTime*i, i);
      }
  },
  sendNotifications = function(i){
      var
      hideTimeout,
      onShow = function(){
          var $this = this;
          hideTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
              $this.close();
          }, displayTime);
      },
      my_notification = new Notify('Hello World ' + i, {
          body: 'Some message here ' + i,
          tag:  "notify_" + i
      });

      my_notification.onShowNotification = onShow;
      my_notification.show();
  }

  if (Notify.needsPermission()) {
      Notify.requestPermission(queueNotifications);
  } else {
       queueNotifications();   
  }
  ```

I've updated your jsfiddle with the working version.
http://jsfiddle.net/e6ps2/5/

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you set the option 'requireInteraction: true' it will stack your notifications for you, they will not disappear automatically as default but you can use the following to hide them.

```
setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 5000);
```